# Knockout JS parameters with Grapnel routing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a knockout app that now requires routing to be implemented. Grapnel looks like a great solution however I've hit a bit of a brick wall with it.

Knockout click events pass the current 'view model' to whatever function you define in your view - as documented [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html). As mentioned this is really useful when working with collections and the app I mention uses this quite a lot.

I'm looking for a way of being able to make use of this from within grapnel routes however I'm lost when it comes to a solution.

I've put together a rather simple fiddle to try to help explain things:
https://jsfiddle.net/nt0j49x7/4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <ul class="playlist" data-bind="foreach: albumList">
    <li class="album">
      <a href="" data-bind="click: $root.showAlbumInfo">
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span> -
        <strong data-bind="text: artist"></strong>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div data-bind="with: selectedAlbum">
    <img data-bind="attr:{src: coverImg}" />
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: title"></span> - <span data-bind="text: artist"></span> 
      <a data-bind="attr:{href: spotifyLink}">Listen on spotify</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var appView = {
    albumList: ko.observableArray([
    {id: 1, title:'Helioscope' , artist: 'Vessels', coverImg: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91nC-KVZBBL._SX466_.jpg', spotifyLink: 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3dARFB98TMzKLHwZOgKZhE'},
    {id: 2, title:'Dilate' , artist: 'Vessels', coverImg: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31AvNaBtnpL._SX466_PJautoripBadge,BottomRight,4,-40_OU11__.jpg', spotifyLink: 'https://open.spotify.com/album/7yapNLdtqlYiGFbuEuGRIt'},
    {id: 3, title:'White fields and open devices' , artist: 'Vessels', coverImg: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/918vEDkM5PL._SX522_PJautoripBadge,BottomRight,4,-40_OU11__.jpg', spotifyLink: 'https://open.spotify.com/album/4kB1vlgei2DvIweeBoiNVu'}
  ]),
  selectedAlbum: ko.observable(),
    showAlbumInfo: function(album, event) {
    // knockout supplies the clicked model value as the first parameter
    appView.selectedAlbum(album);
  }
};

var routes = {
        'album/:id' : function(req, event){
            // Any ideas on how to pass the 'album' object knockout is
      // passing to the appView.showAlbumInfo method into this
      // route handler? I can use the ID request param to
      // get the model from albumList and set the selectedAlbum
      // but that isn't what I'm trying to achieve.
        }
};

//var router = new Grapnel(routes);

ko.applyBindings(appView, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using knockout for year but only took a quick look at Grapnel. I don't see a way of passing objects as parameters.  But this is obviously a single page app approach and you have declare your view model as a global.  So you can access the "appView" within the router code:

```
var router = new Grapnel();
//must include the id in the route for function to fire on id change
router.navigate('/album/' + album.id);
            console.info(appView.selectedAlbum());
        }
);
```

Then in your viewModel event you can navigate after you set the observable.

```
showAlbumInfo: function(album, event) {
    // knockout supplies the clicked model value as the first parameter
    appView.selectedAlbum(album);
    router.navigate('/album/' + album.id);
}
```

fiddle:[example](https://jsfiddle.net/nt0j49x7/9/)
Not sure what your app is going to be but Angular js will do what you are trying to do all in one package with observables and routeing.  You won't need knockout.